# DIsplaying a list of months, with calendar summary of items

Tags: solspace-calendar

Is there an easy way to display a list of 12 months, with the events displayed for each month. Therefore, not dividing each month into days?

A parent summary view to the calendar month page, if you will?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [Calendar:Cal](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/calendar) tag, using the {display_each_month} variable pair. Your code would look something like this:

```
<ul>
{exp:calendar:cal
    channel="calendar_events"
    date_range_start="today"
    show_months="12"
    pad_short_weeks="n"
}

    {display_each_month}
        <li>
            <h3>Month: {date format="%F"} ({month_event_total} events_</h3>
            <ul>
                {events}
                <li><a href="{path="calendar/events"}/{event_id}/">{event_title}</a> &nbsp; {event_start_date format="%F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"} - {event_end_date format="%F %j, %Y at %g:%i%a"}</li>
                {/events}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {/display_each_month}

    {if no_results}
        <li>No results</li>
    {/if}

{/exp:calendar:cal}
</ul>
```